Show that $\sum_{j \in J} \sum_{i\in I_j}f(i) = \sum_{i\in I}f(i)\cdot \operatorname {card}\{j \in J: i \in I_j\}$
Let I be a finite indexing set and $f :I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function.
We know that if $(I_j)_{j \in J}$ is a partition of I, then $\sum_{j \in J} \sum_{i\in I_j}f(i) = \sum_{i \in I}f(i)$
I'm wondering if it's true that if $I =\cup_{j \in J}I_j$ (not necessarily a disjoint union), then:

$\sum_{j \in J} \sum_{i\in I_j}f(i) = \sum_{i\in I}f(i)\cdot \operatorname {card}\{j \in J: i \in I_j\}$

I'm almost convinced that this is true, but I don't know how to prove it, could anyone help me?
I'm trying to use this to prove this

Suppose $I$ and $J$ are finite, and $I_j \subseteq I$ for all $j\in J$.  Then (using Iverson bracket notation) we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\in J} \sum_{i\in I_j} f(i)
&= \sum_{j\in J} \sum_{i\in I} [i\in I_j] f(i) \\
&= \sum_{i\in I} \sum_{j\in J} [i\in I_j] f(i) \\
&= \sum_{i\in I} f(i) \sum_{j\in J} [i\in I_j] \\
&= \sum_{i\in I} f(i) \sum_{j\in J: i\in I_j} 1 \\
&= \sum_{i\in I} f(i) \cdot|\{j\in J: i\in I_j\}|.
\end{align}
Note that this result does not require that $\cup_{j\in J} I_j = I$.
